# Install windows to one hard drive but use another?

Tags: windows, installation

Is it possible to install windows to let's say a 60gb SSD but tell windows to allow folders such as:

Program files
Documents 
Pictures
Movies

And other miscellaneous storage types to be stored on an external hard drive?

The external drive is a 1TB desktop drive which has its own power cord which uses USB 3.0?

Comment: Why external hard drive? You have laptop and you can't put 2 drives in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move Documents, Pictures, Videos, Desktop and other special folders to another disk - no problem. Just go to your C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents folder **Properties**, open **Location** tab and click Move.

[image]

However if your computer start without that external drive - Windows will re-create these special folders in default location and you will have to move them again after you connect HDD.

According Program Files - it is possible to rename or move Program Files and Program Files (x86) directories, but I just create another Program Files directory on second HDD and install very big programs there.

It is good if you have .NET installed on SSD (many programs use .NET libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has Clearly Stated that this is not possible in any way because of the **Hard Coded links and paths** between windows files and programs and that will break their connections and render windows unusable.

> Microsoft does not support changing the location of the Program Files folder by modifying the ProgramFilesDir registry value

Change default Program Files directory
If you almost always prefer to NOT install on the System Disk, but instead on another partition, say, the D drive, then rather than changing the default location every time, you can edit the registry as follows:

1. Open Regedit and navigate to the following key:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
2. Now in the right pane look for the value ProgramFilesDir and/or ProgramFilesDir (x86) depending     on whether your Window 8 is 32-bit or 64-bit.
3. Double click on it and in the box which opens up change its Value data from C:\Program Files to  say, D:\Program Files.
4. Click Ok. Exit.
5. The default directory for installation of all you programs shall now be D:\Program Files. If you are  using Windows 64-bit, you may want to change the value of ProgramFilesDir and ProgramFilesDir (x86).